# Ubuntu in an enterprise: recommendations?

Tags: ubuntu, deployment

I'm going to move a small office to Ubuntu. Typical tasks: VoIP, E-Mail, documents, RDP access, ERP, printing, file-sharing.

What stack of technologies & solutions can you suggest to use for better experience and flexibility? Real-life success stories are welcome :)

Here's a list of possible features to implement:

- Network configuration
- VPN
- Centralized authentication (account management)
- Home directories storage (hardware-independent workplace)
- Simplified Shares/Printers configuration
- Centralized administration & configuration
- Installed software management
- Hardware monitoring
- Helpdesk: remove support
- Documents & PIM sharing/storage system

Comment: I don't want to be a jerk here but you're doing this the wrong way round. You're essentially saying "The answer is ubuntu, now what questions can I make fit into that?" where it might be better to say "What does the business want to do, and what would be a good answer to all of those?"

Comment: You're right, but the boss says 'Ubuntu', so be it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of work involved in just finding out what you really eed let alone making specific recommendations, but to get you started....

You should certainly plan on using LDAP for a lot of the authentication/authorization stuff. I'd recommend [GoSA](https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa/) as a plug-and-play solution.

NFS as a file sharing system makes decoupling users from individual machines very easy - but NFS is not a very secure network file system and has [other problems too](http://www.linuxinsight.com/files/ols2006/kirch-reprint.pdf).

I've not tried myself but you might want to research using SMB for users home dirs - there is a [pam module](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_mount) which handles the mounting of drives.

If all the clients are linux based - then you might consider using scp for shared file access - most modern file managers will happily run on top of ssh (I mostly use KDE - where all file access can be routed through wrappers).

For printing - cups. Its not as well integrated with LDAP as it probably should be - but for most purposes that's not such a big issue. And the only real alternative is the BSD printing system - which is not better for integration and loses out on ease of configuration (IMHO - please don't flame - I still use BSD lpd for managing queueing of non-printer stuff like fax).

There are lots of tools for managing software multiple machines. Canonical's [landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape) is well worth a look - particularly if you're planning on usnig Ubuntu anyway. You don't say how many you're talking about. I'd recommend configuring an ssh server on each box and a GUI server (X, VNC, FreeNX).

> Documents & PIM sharing/storage system

Oooh, that's difficult to give a definitive answer to. [Kolab](http://www.kolab.org/)+Kontact? Evolution+....? Zimbra? These will provide the email/PIM/calendaring document sharing is a different thing altogther.

Comment: http://www.zentyal.org/ is also great & "just works" :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Google Apps to take care of that last bullet point?

That way you don't have to worry about email, calendaring, or document sharing. Plus now with [Google Cloud Connect](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/btl/google-launches-microsoft-office-connector-keep-your-legacy-office-use-our-cloud/41985), you can still continue to use Word and just have it sync to Google's cloud.

Answer (score 1):

VPN: I've used OpenVPN successfully on ubuntu, the authentication was done by LDAP.

Centralized authentication (account management):...LDAP

Helpdesk: remove support: RT is a good tool if you mean ticket system. If you meant remote support, I used TeamViewer, it's cross platform (Windows, MacOS and Linux).

I second Daniel's suggestion for Google Apps. It does take a large amount of work off the sysadmin's shoulders. Plus, it integrates wonderfully with any platform/mail client.